# Do I need Code Analysis in Visual Studios if I'm using FxCop?

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, fxcop

I was going over the settings in my Visual Studio 2017 solution and I'm looking at the Code Analysis tab on my UWP projects.  I'm already importing the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers.  Is the need for Code Analysis in Visual Studio obviated by the FxCopAnalyzer package or are the complimentary?

Comment: My experience since asking this questions is 'no', you don't need it.  The FxCop analyzers seem to pick up everything in the Visual Studio Code Analyzers and more.  I've turned this option off.